# Refresh Cached AD Credentials through VPN to Trusted Domain

Tags: active-directory, vpn

Our infrastructure has 2 domains, one is on premises and the other is in AWS, both Windows Active Directory.  There is a one way trust setup so that the AWS domain can authenticate resources based on on-premises domain users, but not the other way around.

I work remotely and have joined my work computer to the on-premises domain using the on-premises VPN, but I have no reason to connect to the on-premises VPN for day-to-day tasks.  All of my work is done using AWS resources but I am required to use and authenticate with a user account from the om-premises domain.

The cached credentials from the intitial domain connection on the work computer work fine for some time, but eventually stop working causing the trust relationship to break and I have to leave and rejoin the domain.

The network team has infomred me that the only way to prevent this is to routinely connect to the on-premises VPN to update the cached credentials.

Is there any way to update my cached credentials through the AWS VPN and not the on-premisis VPN?

Comment: Your user account credentials is not related to the computer trust relationship breaking.

Comment: So network guys are wrong?  How do I keep the trust relationship from breaking?

Comment: Anyone saying that a user account can cause a computer account trust relationship to break is incorrect.

Comment: that's great to know, but what's the solution to preventing it?